# copy paste automatic range from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to perform a copy past from one book to another. i searched everywhere in the web but, i must admin, I am not that into VBA so to understand properly the solutions people are providing. The code I wrote is this. 
Step by step:
I define the variables. Define the ranges from where to take the year, month and day corresponding to the file i want to open. I open the file. I set the destination book as my current book (where i put the button). Then I want to find the automatic range of my tab (since everyday changes) and i perform a counting of columns (-5 since i do not need the last 5 columns) and rows as discussed in various courses. But.. the code stops after I open the book (wkbk). Why is that? The error that comes out is: application defined or object defined error.

```
    Sub Opentrading()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Path As String
Dim nyear As String
Dim nmont As String
Dim nday As String
Dim wkbk As Workbook
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

FolderPath = "F:\FICM\Trading Runs\Daily Trading Runs"
nyear = Sheet6.Range("J3")
nmont = Sheet6.Range("J5")
nday = Sheet6.Range("J7")
Path = FolderPath & "\" & nyear & "-" & nmont & "-" & nday & " Trading - Southern_Europe" & ".xlsx"
Set mybook = ThisWorkbook
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set sht = wkbk.Sheets("Southern_Europe")

'Find Last Row and Column
Set StartCell = Range("D1")
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
 wkbk.Worksheets("Southern_Europe").Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn - 5)).Copy mybook.Worksheets("Prova").Range("Z1")

  wkbk.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Saverio, the question of SJR was on which line is the error.

Comment: immediately after the wkbk=open(path)

as soon as the program opens the file (either with f8 or running the entire code), it gives the error

Comment: @Saverio - does the worksheet `"Southern_Europe"` exist?

Comment: Vityata below spotted the error! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Set StartCell = Range("D1")
```

To:

```
Set StartCell = sht.Range("D1")
```

You are using the `StartCell` here:

```
wkbk.Worksheets("Southern_Europe").Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn - 5)).Copy
```

And if the `StartCell` is not declared correctly, it does not belong to the worksheet "Southern_Europe". On the contrary, it takes the `ActiveSheet` or the worksheet in which it is currently.